# Missing qmacdefines_mac.h file from qtgui.framework

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5

I am upgrading some qt projects from qt version 4 to version 5 on mac(mavericks). For that, i built qt5 from source and modified projects to use the qt5 lib which i built.

In my code, i am using qwidget method in my derived class:

virtual bool macEvent(EventHandlerCallRef caller, EventRef event)

But i get "Unknown type name EventHandlerCallRef" and "Unknown type name EventRef". After searching for this in qt 4, i found it inside "qmacdefines_mac.h" in QtGui.framework/... but i could not find same file in qt 5 QtGui.framework.

Did i miss any flag while building qt 5?

Comment: In your situation, I would `$grep -r EventHandlerCallRef` from the Qt source directory, in a terminal.

Comment: macEvent was deprecated and replaced with [`nativeEvent(const QByteArray & eventType, void * message, long * result)`]( http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#nativeEvent)

Comment: No, for qt4, qmacdefines_mac.h was in built lib/QtGui.Framework which was used by my old qt projects. Now, this file is not there in new(qt5) lib/QtGui.Framework and because of this, i get above errors while building my upgraded qt projects. So, my question is,  should this file be in lib/QtGui.Framework after building qt 5 source? Am i missing any qt 5 source build/configure steps on mac?